# Do commit after method execution - decorator

Tags: python, wrapper, decorator

I'm new in decorators and I'm trying to create one, which do `self.commit()` after the method is executed.

I have a problem with arguments. The method commit (decorator) is inside the class.

```
def commit(func):
    def func_wrapper(func):
        func()
        self.commit()
    return func_wrapper
```

I made a testing method:

```
@commit
def h(self):
    pass
```

And calling it:

```
db = database()
db.create_tables()
db.h()
```

ERROR: `TypeError: commit() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

I do know that the error is being raised because it is not a static method, so I tried to put there `self` argument but still errors are appearing.

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You build decorators for methods the same way as for functions, but **you need to take the `self` into consideration of the wrapper function**:

```
def commit(func):
    def func_wrapper(self):
        func(self)
        self.commit()
    return func_wrapper
```

---

*Update:*

A better approach would be to **make the decorator useful for functions *and* methods**. This could be done by putting `*args` and `**kwargs` as parameters for the wrapper, so it can accept *any arbitrary* number of arguments and keyword arguments.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks but now, it should be a static method? Or should I put it outside of the class? It tells that commit should have self parameter.

Comment: @Milan: see my updated answer or *a_guest* answer. No it could be normal method.

Comment: `self` is just the binding of a name to a variable (most likely the instance you want to refer to). Conventionally it is used for the instance an instance method is called on. But of course `self` can be used in other contexts as well.

Comment: @a_guest: Yes you are absolutely right :) However, it would be be better to put `args` and `**kwargs` as parameters for the wrapper, then it can accept any arbitrary number of arguments and keyword arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the actual argument to the wrapper function and call the decorated function with that argument:

```
def commit(func):
    def func_wrapper(self):
        func(self)
        self.commit()
    return func_wrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass arguments for the function, as earlier posts said. But you most likely don't want to restrict arguments your function takes in the decorator, use `*args`, `**kwargs` for that. Lastly, it's a good idea to use [functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to preserve original function metadata.

Complete example:

```
from functools import wraps

def commit(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.commit()
    return wrapper
```